# Twillio just make a call say a confirmation token and hangup

Tags: ruby, twilio

I'm sending confirmation token to my users to verify their phone number as a message, I want to add the option for call, just in case sms delivery had any problem. for example I need to make a call and say "Your confirmation token is 123456" and hangup, this is the code:

```
  def connect
    render text: 'message parameter not found!' if params[:message].blank?
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Say "hello world", :voice => 'alice'
      r.
    end

    # Render response as xml
    #response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml"
    render text: response.text, :status => :ok
  end

  def call
    account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
    auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    mobile = params[:mobile]
    message = params[:message]
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @call = @client.account.calls.create(
            :from => ENV["TWILIO_MOBILE"],
            :to => mobile,
            :url => "https://server_address/connect"
    )

    render json: {result:'call executed.'}, :status => :ok
  end
```

destination phone number rings but it just says "An Application Error Occured" and hangs up. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think there's a couple of problems here, but nothing that can't be overcome!

Firstly, you have a double render error in your `connect` action. If the message parameter isn't present your action will try to `render text: 'message parameter not found!'`, however it will not stop there and will also try tp render the twiml as well.

This wouldn't have shown up as an issue were the message parameter present. Thing is, in your `call` action you provide the URL for the call to connect to, but you don't include the message parameter. If you changed the line on which you create the call to:

```
@call = @client.account.calls.create(
  :from => ENV["TWILIO_MOBILE"],
  :to => mobile,
  :url => "https://server_address/connect?message=#{message}"
)
```

then your message parameter will be set when the `connect` action is called when the phone number is answered.

Lastly, watch out, you have a hanging method call within your TwiML response. There is a trailing `r.` with no verb in your example. That would cause problems to.

Try out those suggestions and let me know if that works.